# How to access array within associative array in jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, frontend

I am retrieving JSON data from a remote server in an associative array format . The structure of the associative array is:

```
data=
{
"1":[{"project_id":1,"project":"IET1"},{"project_id":2,"project":"IET2"}],
"2":[{"project_id":3,"project":"IET3"}],
"3":[{"project_id":4,"project":"IET4"},{"project_id":5,"project":"IET5"}]
}
```

This is the exact format that I am getting from the ajax response. Now when I trying to traverse it using the following way:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(data, function (key, value) {
  alert(key + " " + value) // will alert => "project_id 1"
}
```

I am trying to iterate using the main index ("1", "2" etc).
How can I do this? I have a searched a lot but I didn't find any solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Object.keys might help you. This is a nested loop.. but works

```
let data = `{
    "1":[{"project_id":1,"project":"IET1"},{"project_id":2,"project":"IET2"}],
    "2":[{"project_id":3,"project":"IET3"}],
    "3":[{"project_id":4,"project":"IET4"},{"project_id":5,"project":"IET5"}]
}`;

data = JSON.parse(data)
const keys = Object.keys(data);

keys.forEach(key => data[key].forEach(project => console.log(project.project_id + " - " + project.project)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the "reviver" call back function within `JSON.parse()` - that is used to transform the data as it is parsed.

Just parse it. then you can retrieve the keys if you want them or iterate over them using `for in` loop.

```js
let data = `{
"1":[{"project_id":1,"project":"IET1"},{"project_id":2,"project":"IET2"}],
"2":[{"project_id":3,"project":"IET3"}],
"3":[{"project_id":4,"project":"IET4"},{"project_id":5,"project":"IET5"}]
}`;

const out = JSON.parse(data);

const keys = Object.keys(out);

for (key in out) {
  alert(out[key][0].project);
  console.log(key, out[key]);
}
```

Comment: one thing I wanna to ask more that how can I get the project_id, project etc in an alert?